# Дан список цифр от 1 до n найти умножение двух элементов равное сумме списка без этих двух элементов? Как ускорить код?

Tags: python, алгоритм, оптимизация

```
def remov_nb(n):
    l1 = []
    l = list(range(1, n+1))
    for x in l:
        i = 1
        while i < len(l):
            if sum(l)-x-l[i] == x *l[i]:
                l2=(x, l[i])
                l1.append(l2)
                i+=1
            else:
                i += 1

    return l1
```

Comment: `sum(l)` из цикла вынесите.

Comment: От цикла `while` можно избавиться. Если известно первое число, второе вычисляется арифметикой.

Comment: я сам придумал без while но по скорости не прошло может из за списка

Comment: *n = 2206298*. 23 решения: *(1112671, 2187415), (1124661, 2164095), (1132768, 2148607), (1172730, 2075391), (1196887, 2033503), (1249951, 1947175), (1285327, 1893583), (1294047, 1880823), (1301838, 1869567), (1320703, 1842862), (1340263, 1815967), (1367871, 1779315), (1377151, 1767325), (1398033, 1740927), (1416127, 1718683), (1436511, 1694295), (1441705, 1688191), (1477167, 1647663), (1478911, 1645720), (1482508, 1641727), (1487815, 1635871), (1529923, 1590847), (1548235, 1572031)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сумма чисел от *1* до *n* равна *n(n + 1)/2*. Обозначим её *s*.

Нужно найти *a* и *b* такие что *s - a - b = ab*, *1 ≤ a < b ≤ n*.

Вынесем *b*: *s - a = (a + 1)b*. В итоге *b = (s - a) / (a + 1)*.

Список не нужен, внутренний `while` тоже. Перебор по всем *a*. *b* вычисляется:

```
def solve(n):
    s = n * (n + 1) // 2
    for a in range(1, n + 1):
        if (s - a) % (a + 1) == 0:
            b = (s - a) // (a + 1)
            if a < b <= n:
                yield a, b


def main():
    n = 1
    while True:
        answer = tuple(solve(n))
        if answer:
            print(n, answer)
        n += 1


main()
```

Дальше. *b* должно быть целое. То есть *(s - a) ⫶ (a + 1)*, что равносильно *(s - a + a + 1) ⫶ (a + 1)*. Получаем *(s + 1) ⫶ (a + 1)*. Вместо перебора всех *а* можно перебрать делители *s + 1*, что быстрее.

```
import math


def factors(n):
    i = 2
    j = n
    j_sqrt = math.isqrt(j)
    while i <= j_sqrt:
        if j % i == 0:
            p = 0
            while j % i == 0:
                j //= i
                p += 1
            yield i, p
            j_sqrt = math.isqrt(j)
        i += 1 if i == 2 else 2
    if j > 1:
        yield j, 1


def divisors(n):
    f = tuple(factors(n))

    def search(i):
        if i == len(f):
            yield 1
            return
        p, e = f[i]
        for d in search(i + 1):
            yield d
            for _ in range(e):
                d *= p
                yield d

    yield from search(0)


def solve(n):
    s = n * (n + 1) // 2
    for d in divisors(s + 1):
        a = d - 1
        if 1 <= a < n:
            assert (s - a) % (a + 1) == 0
            b = (s - a) // (a + 1)
            if a < b <= n:
                yield a, b


def main():
    n = 1
    while True:
        answer = tuple(sorted(solve(n)))
        if answer:
            print(n, answer)
        n += 1


main()
```